# Can't use USB adapter 0846:9014 NetGear, Inc. in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, ubuntu-drivers

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside with Windows 10 and when I am trying to connect to WiFi, i can´t even see it there as an option.
This is what I see[image]

I have disabled Secure Boot in Bios and after running `sudo lshw -C network`, all I see is this

[image]

Despite searching online on how to install or update the wifi drivers, I haven't found anything that works for me. Any help will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I followed the suggestion of @Mahesh and as you can read in my comment below, on the top right corner where I was seeing the icon to connect to the internet ( the first picture of my question), I cannot see anything now, and I am freaking out. Can you please help?

Output of `lspci` here:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Q87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Integrated Technology Express, Inc. IT8893E PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 41)
```

output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04b3:3025 IBM Corp. NetVista Full Width Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0846:9014 NetGear, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci` terminal command.

Comment: Apparently I have to earn at least 10 reputation to have more than 2 images in my question, so i cannot include the output of  `lspci`

Comment: I posted it as an answer hope it helps

Comment: Are you using an external USB adapter? There is no PCI adapter in your system, or it is disabled in BIOS.

Comment: Yes I am using an external usb adapter

Comment: How do we know that before? Then post the output of `lsusb`.

Comment: i have done it already, look the question

Comment: You did not. You posted `lspci` that is not relevant because you are using a USB adapter.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that you need to post the output of `lsusb` to your question. So we see what adapter you are using.

Comment: See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2291817

Comment: but this is not helping for the internet options menu to re-appear

Comment: What "this" does not help? The adapter is not supported by linux drivers. As far as I got it, you have to install Windows drivers using `ndiswrapper` to get it working. It is much easier to buy a supported dongle.

Comment: By " this "  i mean the problem that i describe in the  **Update** part of my question

Comment: That answer is blatantly not relevant to your case.

Answer (score -1):

Restart network manager.

> sudo service network-manager restart

Restart the nm applet.

> killall nm-applet && nm-applet &

then

> sudo lshw -class network

output look like this

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 59
       serial: 60:57:18:78:f9:92
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-28-generic firmware=16.242414.0 ip=192.168.1.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:49 memory:f7000000-f7001fff
```

With the above information available to us we can go to work and try to solve the resume from suspend issue.

```
sudo vi /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

In this file, paste the following

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="iwlwifi wlp2s0"
```

Now, issue a restart of the network manager

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

that's it.

Comment: I did the 3 first commands and the output did not look like this. I was seeing Ethernet in the decription.  I don´t know why i didn´t stop there, but I tried also the `sudo vi /etc/pm/config.d/config` and then I was seeing a black terminal where I didn´t know where to put the  `SUSPEND_MODULES="iwlwifi wlp2s0"  `. I tried to paste it and nothing was happening. So i exited the terminal and now i dont even see any internet connection options available. Nothing. What did just happen Mahesh? How can i fix this??

Comment: try this
==> sudo lshw -class bridge

Comment: I did, but still nothing